# How to override parts of a method of a base class in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have `Class B` that derives from `Class A`.

How can I override parts of `Draw` method in `Class A` and keep parts of it and throw away the rest?

For example here I want the `Draw` method in `Class B` to `DrawRectangles()` and instead of `DrawrCircles` to `DrawTriangles`.

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void Draw()
    {
       DrawRectangles();
       DrawCircles();
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void Draw()
    {
        // I want to still draw rectangles
        // but I do not want to draw circles
        // I want to draw triangles instead
    }
}
```

Comment: Feels more like a bad design than anything else here.

Comment: You could use an interface and implement the base methods in 2 separate classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with the below:

```
public class A
{
    public virtual void OverridableDraw()
    {
        DrawCircles();  // declare all those which can be overrided here
    }
    public void Draw()
    {
        DrawRectangles(); // declare methods, which will not change
    }
}
public class B : A
{
    public override void OverridableDraw()
    {
        // just override here
    }
}
```

The Idea is to override only those, which tends to change.

Then, you can call both the methods.

```
OverridableDraw();
Draw();
```

Comment: Thanks Amit for the practical solution instead of showing off under the question.

Comment: glad to have helped you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Then why don't you just call the methods you want to execute ?

```
public override void Draw()
{
     DrawRectangles();
     DrawTriangles();
}
```

There is no partially overriding for methods.You can declare [partial methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wa80x488.aspx) but they are not the same.If you want to override, you need to overrride whole method.

Comment: Up for simplicity given the post's lack of instructions.

Comment: Selman22 I have lots of methods that are in common and lots of them that are different from the base class. So I need to hide the different ones in base class.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative design, if you have lots of different 'parts' you have to draw, and have not so much alternate drawing, I'd personally use a [Flag] enumeration

```
[Flags]
public enum DrawParts
{
    Rectangles = 1,
    Circles = 2,
    Triangles = 4,
    //etc
}
public class A
{
    //or a regular get/setter instead of a virtual property
    public virtual DrawParts DrawMode { get { return DrawParts.Rectangles | DrawParts.Circles; } } 
    public void Draw()
    {
        var mode = DrawMode;
        if (mode.HasFlag(DrawParts.Circles))
            DrawCircles();
        if (mode.HasFlag(DrawParts.Rectangles)) //NB, not elseif
            DrawRectangles();
        //etc
    }

}

public class B : A
{
    public override DrawParts DrawMode{get{return DrawParts.Rectangles | DrawParts.Triangles; }}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Me.Name, this answer is a bit complex but thank you for the insight to look at this from another point of view.